# Trying to access form input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm quite new to web development and I'm trying to access form data in my javascript file but can't manage to do it. Here it is:

My HTML:

```js
var name = document.getElementById('loginForm').value;
console.log(name);
```

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  Username <input type="text" name="username" value="Donald"><br> Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="Duck"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="module" src="other.js"></script>
```

The reason I've done it in a separate javascript file is that I'll be calling APIs later on. No matter what I've tried, 'name' is always Donald instead of what I enter into my form and I'm not sure how I can access it if I remove value from the input tags.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to select the input tag and get the value try this `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("value");`

Comment: @Sara he already got the value `'name' is always Donald`

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara — That will make the problem worse. The value *attribute* (as opposed to the property they are currently using) will always be the default value (so if they make the change you propose, they will have *two* different causes of the symptoms they are experiencing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script will be called on load what means it will always return the default value `Donald`.

So to get the new value you could attach a click event to a button then when you click you'll get the current value like :

```js
document.getElementById('showName').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value);
})
```

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="Donald">
  <br> Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="Duck">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Show value" id="showName" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is is also important that when you handle a submit event on the form instead of a click on a button things differ somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the value outside of any function, so the value will be whatever it is at the time the `<script>` is loaded.

If you want to read the value at some other time, you'll need to wrap the code in a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and call it *later*.

How you do that depends on the particular *later* that you care about. Most likely you should bind the function as an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Maybe to the `input` event of the text box, or the `submit` event of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("loginForm"));
var inputValue = form.get("username");
```

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  Username <input type="text" name="username" value="Donald"><br> Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="Duck"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="module" src="other.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the form el and not the input el.
Also you need onchange listener.

```
var el = document.getElementsByName('username')[0];
var value = el.value;
console.log(value);//Donald

el.onchange = function(e){
   console.log(e.target.value); // new value any time you change it in the input
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not show anything different is that you only access it initially, not after any changes. for a submit or other event.  In order to access after a change you have to monitor for that change event, same for a submit, then access the form in an event handler for that event.

```js
var username = document.getElementById('username');
console.log(username.value);
var myform = document.getElementById('loginForm');

username.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
  console.log(event.target.value);
  console.log('Element change through function!');
});
myform.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  var thisform = this;// refer to form (see below)
  event.preventDefault(); // stop the submit for now
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(thisform.password.value);//use form field by name
  console.log(event.type);// submit
  console.log(username.value);// from the id reference
  console.log('Form submit through function!');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  <label class="label">Username: <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="Donald"></label>
  <label class="label">Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="Duck"></label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="module" src="other.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey friends,You have typo in your code in line 14, `sonsole.log('Form submit through function!');` should be `console.log('Form submit through function!');`